# Variable based on switch in Google apps

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to create a script where a variable 'LectEmail' would be assigned depending on a selection in Google forms. I do not know if I am writing the switch statement in the correct format:

```
function myFunction(e){
    var group = e.values[0];
    var StudentName = e.values[1];
    var StudentEmail = e.values[2];
  var Score = e.values[3];
  var LectEmail = "";
  switch (LectEmail) {
    case group == "1A":
      LectEmail = "1A@gmail.com";
      break;

      case group == "2A":
      LectEmail = "2A@gmail.com";
      break; }


  var subject = "Form Submitted";
    var message = "Thank you," + group;

MailApp.sendEmail (LectEmail, subject, message);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your switch statement is wrong, you need to make switch always open so that cases can be executed. To make switch open give `true` inside the bracket

```
function myFunction(e){
  var group = e.values[0];
  var StudentName = e.values[1];
  var StudentEmail = e.values[2];
  var Score = e.values[3];
  var LectEmail = "";
  switch (true) { //Switch will be always open//
    case group == "1A":
      LectEmail = "1A@gmail.com";
      break;

    case group == "2A":
      LectEmail = "2A@gmail.com";
      break; 
  }

  var subject = "Form Submitted";
  var message = "Thank you," + group;

  MailApp.sendEmail (LectEmail, subject, message);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Issue:

The syntax is `switch(expr){case 'one': ...}`. Here , `expr` is compared against case `one`: If true, that block is evaluated. Your `expr`: `LectEmail` is compared against case `group == "1A"`(which in itself will  evaluate to `true/false`).

#### Solution:

Use `group` as `expr` and modify case accordingly

#### Snippet:

```
  switch (group) {//modified
    case "1A"://modified
      LectEmail = "1A@gmail.com";
      break;
```

#### To Read:

[Switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)